# Embarrassingly parallel for loops

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, joblib

I have a simplified source code loop like belows and I want to speed up by using parallel computing. 
Unfortunately, I can not use `holder` by passing by reference among threads. The ordinary programming with out threading works fine with this, but when I start using concurrent style. It does not work.

**Questions:**
Where am I wrong?
What kind of knowledge do I need to use?
My background is non-computer science and very new to this topic

**Output:**

```
result: [None, None, None, None, None]
len(result): 5
ans: []
```

**my_code.py:**

```
import multiprocessing

from joblib import Parallel, delayed

num_cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count()


def prepare_row(holder, aa, bb, cc, my_int, gso=None):
    my_dict = {
        "first": aa,
        "second": bb,
        "third": cc,
        "my_int": my_int,
        "gso": gso,
    }
    holder.append(my_dict)


def exp1():
    holder = []
    gso = "111"

    def node_shortcut(i):
        return i, 2 * i, i + 1

    for item in range(1, 5):
        aa, bb, cc = node_shortcut(item)
        my_int = aa + 1

        result = Parallel(n_jobs=num_cores, verbose=5)(
            delayed(prepare_row)(holder, aa, bb, cc, my_int, gso=gso) for imei in range(1, 6))
    print(f"result: {result}")
    print(f"len(result): {len(result)}")
    return holder


if __name__ == "__main__":
    ans = exp1()
    print(f"ans: {ans}")
```

Comment: Please give more detail on what "It does not work" means.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your attention. I just update my question